# Parameter 0 of constructor in ..RoleService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a basic spring boot application and when I try to implement a repository i keep getting this error:

```
    Description:

    Parameter 0 of constructor in com.frana.taskme.services.RoleService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

    Action:

    Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

I've used all kind of Annotations in the Application.java and all kind of properties and nothing changes.

This is my repository where you can find the app: https://github.com/franagibo/test

Is there some problem with the dependencies of the pom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your pom.xml jpa dependency from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Remove from `application.propertiesspring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration`

Dont forget to update the dependencies, you might need to clean m2/repository.

Comment: Ok so ive done what you told me and.. it works! Sadly now ive got some problem with the DataSource connection. Im using a local DB with MySQLExpress and a windows authentication to login. I think the problem is still in my application.properties but i cant figure out what it is. Any ideas?


This is a previous post ive made where you can find screenshots of my db configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371029/connect-to-localdb-with-windows-authentication

Comment: @FranaGrana since now you got a different problem, and the one from this question was answered, could you mark this question as answered ? For the other question, I would suggest to update it or create a new one with the DataSource error you get and your github repository. Also, are you using Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL? They are different and require different dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

you are excluding the autoconfiguration on your application.properties

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

which means you have to manually define your DataSource, SessionFactory, EntityManager ...

Comment: I've removed that line from the properties but I still get the same error